# Keys from the Secure Enclave returns empty string

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am trying to use the code below to store credentials to my Keychain manager and it seems to save successfully, but when I try to retrieve the code, it is returning an empty string instead. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong, but I'm sure it's minor. Any help is appreciated.

#### Code for storage

```
let credentials = Credentials(email: txtEmail.text ?? "", password: txtPassword.text ?? "")
KeychainManager.storeCredentials(credentials: credentials)
```

When I placed a breakpoint, I debugged to make sure that it is passing in actual values into the storeCredentials function

#### Code for retrieval

```
var credentials = KeychainManager.fetchCredentials()
txtEmail.text = credentials.email
txtPassword.text = credentials.password
```

#### Keychain manager

```
class KeychainManager {
    
    static let server = "xyz"
    
    enum KeychainError: Error {
        case noPassword
        case unexpectedPasswordData
        case unhandledError(status: OSStatus)
    }
    
    static func storeCredentials(credentials: Credentials) {
        print("Storing user credentials...")
        
        let account = credentials.email
        let password = credentials.password.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let query: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassInternetPassword,
                                    kSecAttrAccount as String: account,
                                    kSecAttrServer as String: server,
                                    kSecValueData as String: password]
        
        let status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
        
        if status == errSecSuccess { print("Successfully added credentials") } else { print(status.description) }
    }
    
    static func fetchCredentials() -> Credentials {
        
        var email = ""
        var pass = ""
        
        let query: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassInternetPassword,
                                    kSecAttrServer as String: server,
                                    kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne,
                                    kSecReturnAttributes as String: true,
                                    kSecReturnData as String: true]
        
        var item: CFTypeRef?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &item)
        if status != errSecItemNotFound { print("No Password") }
        if status == errSecSuccess { print(status) }
        
        if let existingItem = item as? [String : Any],
            let passwordData = existingItem[kSecValueData as String] as? Data,
            let password = String(data: passwordData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8),
            let account = existingItem[kSecAttrAccount as String] as? String {
            print("Successful retrieval of credentials: ")
            print("Email: " + account)
            print("Password: " + password)
            email = account
            pass = password
        } else {
            print("Unexpected password data")
        }
        
        let credentials = Credentials(email: email, password: pass)
        return credentials
    }
}

struct Credentials {
    var email: String
    var password: String
}
```

The logs show:

```
Successful retrieval of credentials: 
Email: 
Password:
```

Comment: If you store credentials, I assume the code logs „Successfully added credentials“. But what is logged if you try to fetch it?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I updated the question with the log

Comment: Your code follows **exactly** the example in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items?language=objc). Thus an absolutely silly question: Maybe your email and password are really empty?